# Как считывать список из файла, чтобы он читался в виде списка, а не строки?

Tags: python, файлы

```py
import math, os
from math import e
def val():
    if 0<x<10:
        return 2*e**3.14*x
    else:
        return 0
file=open('listfile.txt')
s=file.read()
s1=[]
for x in s:
    s1.append(val())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s = file.readlines()
```

Соответствующий [раздел документации](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).